# How selec .txt file from pc an paste the content to text area on html5

Tags: javascript, html

Hi everyone i'm trying to use Jquery and Modernizr to select 1 .txt file from my pc

I have the next code on my project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Read file on HTML5</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="modernizr.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if (Modernizr.draganddrop && window.FileList) {
                } else {
                    alert("Your browser doesn't support API or Drag&Drop");
                }
                ;
                $('#file').change(filedriver);

                function filedriver(event) {
                    var file = event.target.files[0];

                    if(file.type !== "text/plain"){
                        alert("File .txt must be select");
                        return;
                    }

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event){
                  var textResult = event.target.result;
                  $('content').append(textResult);
                };

                    reader.readAsText(file);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Read file on HTML5</h1>
        <form>
            <label>Select file </label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            <p>Content on file</p>
            <textarea cols="100" rows="15" id="content"></textarea>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i execute the proyect on my browser the validation for the file works, but the reader doesn't return the content on the file.
¿where it's my error?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxrvou2spfdjgte/LecturaArchivoTexto.rar?dl=0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpuAz.jpg)

Comment: $('#content').val(textResult);

Comment: rookie bug, tnx